# pick only latest record by ID in python

Tags: python, date, transactions

I am looking for a way in python to only select latest date observations by ID. What would be the best most efficient way to do it? (I do not want to sort, I want to isolate only latest observations) I have tried the following:

```
data1.loc[data1.groupby('id')['date'].idxmax()]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example of the DataFrame? It would help with an answer.

Comment: Along with data frame can you tell how it fails?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample dataframe**

**data1:**

```
    id  date
0   id1 2019-03-19
1   id1 2019-01-11
2   id1 2019-07-23
3   id2 2020-04-03
4   id2 2020-02-03
```

This will do:

```
data1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data1.date)
data1.groupby(["id"]).agg({'date' : np.max})
```

---

```
    date
id  
id1 2019-07-23
id2 2020-04-03
```